# Magento 2 - Where is jquery code of click on place order button in checkout page?

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, shipping, billing

I want to find jquery code and execute order processing when click on place order in checkout page beacuse i logged in and when I select shipping address and switch to payment step and unchecked of same as shipping address in billing and add new billing address and when I click place order button it automatically checked checkobx of 'My billing address as shipping address'.

Comment: not sure, check this code : skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/opcheckout.js

Comment: @BabyinMagento I am asking for magento 2

Answer (score 2):

These two files.

PATH:

> html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js:12

.

> html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/review/actions/default.js:17

Answer (score 1):

PATH :

> magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/{{THEME}}/en_US/Magento‌​_Checkout/js/action/‌​place-order.js

Comment: He/she is asking for magento 2 not for magento 1

Comment: I am asking magento 2

Comment: Where is this skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js path in magento 2 ?

Comment: If you tell me where is located  after click place order jquery ajax process data I will accept your answer and up vote for you

Comment: Here is the place order js ,

PATH : magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/{{THEME}}/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order.js

Answer (score 1):

Click on place order button in checkout page called on the file :

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order'
], function (quote, urlBuilder, customer, placeOrderService) {
    'use strict';

    return function (paymentData, messageContainer) {
        var serviceUrl, payload;

        payload = {
            cartId: quote.getQuoteId(),
            billingAddress: quote.billingAddress(),
            paymentMethod: paymentData
        };

        if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/payment-information', {});
        } else {
            serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:quoteId/payment-information', {
                quoteId: quote.getQuoteId()
            });
            payload.email = quote.guestEmail;
        }

        return placeOrderService(serviceUrl, payload, messageContainer);
    };
});
```

Answer (score -2):

try to add custom code here

```
/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js
```